# Why is there a syntax error - at 0 in this Couchbase N1QL query?

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++

I have a document in Couchbase:

```
{
  "ResponseMessage": {
    "0": {
      "y2": "1",
      "y1": "2"  
    },
    "1": { 
      "x1": "499",
      "x2": "O"
    },
    "CacheTimeOut": "0",
    "ObjectID": "6632 87d7"
  }
}
```

when I execute this query,

```
select ResponseMessage.0.y1 from `my-bucket`
```

I receive this response:

```
[
  {
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - at 0",
    "query": "select ResponseMessage.0.y1 from `my-bucket`"
  }
]
```

If "0" is "a0" instead, it is does not return an error.

Is it possible to write reference the "0" JSON key name in a N1QL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 is a literal number (in both JSON and N1QL). Therefore, you will need to escape it.

The solution is :

```
select ResponseMessage.`0`.y1 from `my-bucket`
```

Use this character **`** (backtick) to escape

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/identifiers.html

Comment: added documentation link